# magento compilation mode vs apc

Tags: performance, magento, compilation, magento-1.7, apc

Magento has a compilation mode in which you can compile all files of a Magento installation in order to create a single include path to increase performance. http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path  http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_compiler/process/index

In my current shop setup, I have already configured apc to be used as an opcode cache, and am leveraging its performance gains. http://www.aitoc.com/en/blog/apc_speeds_up_Magento.html

My question are:

1) Is there any advantage of using apc over magento compilation mode, or vice versa? I have a dedicated server for magento, and am looking for maximum performance gains.

2) Will it be useful to use both of these togather? Why, or why not?

Comment: realpath_cache_size=128k and realpath_cache_ttl=7200 in the system php.ini for those times when adding a much needed module causes compilation to cough up the nastiest hairball you ever saw. You won't be able to use the compiler, but apc + realpath_cache give you a usable performance boost.

Comment: in addition if you want to speed up your page further, you should not rely on the default file cache. if you want to use the file cache use at least a ram drive. better use memchache or even better use redis :)
https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis

Comment: @Fantus That's interesting :)

Comment: @FiascoLabs Will check your suggestions out.

Comment: @anshol yesterday 1.8 CE was released and the option for cache + session handling by redis now integrated by default
for details:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/redis-magento-ce-ee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These do different things so both together is fine. APC will usually give the greater performance gain that simply enabling compilation, but doing both gives you the best of both worlds.

Just remember when you have enabled compilation you need to disable it before making any code changes or updating/installing modules, then recompile after.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnBoy has already said in his answer, both can be used in conjunction.
Beyond that, another concern was, if using apc would make the compilation redundant.

So I verified the scenario with some `siege` load tests and overall, there is  definite improvement happening.

Here are the test results

`siege --concurrent=50 --internet --file=urls.txt --verbose --benchmark --reps=30 --log=compilation.log`

```
-------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
|Compilation |Date & Time         |Trans  |Elap Time  |Data Trans  |Resp Time  |Trans Rate  |Throughput  |Concurrent  |OKAY    |Failed |
-------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| 
|No          |2013-09-26 12:27:23 |   600 |    202.37 |          6 |      9.79 |       2.96 |       0.03 |      29.01 |    600 |      0|
-------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Yes         |2013-09-26 12:34:05 |   600 |    199.78 |          6 |      9.73 |       3.00 |       0.03 |      29.24 |    600 |      0|
-------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|No          |2013-09-26 12:59:42 |  1496 |    510.40 |         17 |      9.97 |       2.93 |       0.03 |      29.23 |   1496 |      4|
-------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Yes         |2013-09-26 12:46:05 |  1500 |    491.98 |         17 |      9.59 |       3.05 |       0.03 |      29.24 |   1500 |      0|
-------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

There was a certain amount of variance; however, the good thing was that *there was always some improvement*, however miniscule be it.

So we can use both.

The only extra overhead here is disabling and recompiling after module changes.